# How to handle OnReadyStateChanged event in iframe (in IE11)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have a chunk of code with a function attached to the `onreadystatechanged` event of an iFrame.  In IE8 there was an attribute available called `readyState`.

This event still fires in IE11, but my Googling shows that the `readyState` property of the iFrame is no longer available in IE11 (also the `onreadystatechanged` appears to be remove from the script object, but not the iFrame).

So how does one determine the `readyState` in the `onreadystatechange` event of an iFrame now that this attribute seems to be gone?

Comment: How about using the standard `load` event?

Comment: I tried onload.  It does not fire when onreadystatechanged does.  It fires once when the iFrame's parent loads using the iFrame's default src.  What I'm doing is resetting the src to a new page.  When this happens, the iFrame's onload does not fire again at all.  But onreadystatechange fires twice (presumeably once for 'interactive' and again for 'complete'.  However, the readyState property isn't available to tell me what state it is actually in.  This is the crux of what I need to know--why does the event exist when it's most crucial property does not?